# Change to a different folder automatically on Linux once you login

Tags: linux, cd

How can I change to a different folder, e.g. `foo/bar`, automatically once I login into a Linux machine?

```
cd foo/bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **logging** shell you must modify `.bash_profile`. Simply put `cd foo/bar` at the end of this file.

Extra information: https://linuxize.com/post/bashrc-vs-bash-profile/ `.bash_profile` vs `.bashrc`

---

With your distro, if `.bash_profile` does not exist, you can modify `.profile` instead:

> ```
> # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
> # This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
> # exists.
> ```

---

If you want to test it works from a terminal, but logged as `another_user`, you can do:

```
su -l user_to_test
```

The important part is the `-l` flag:

> ```
>   -, -l, --login
>           Start the shell as a login shell with an environment 
>           similar to a real login:
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As is usual, this answer assumes the use of Bash.

When logging in via SSH, I found `~/.bashrc` not to get sourced if I even created `~/.bash_profile`. Note that `~/.bash_profile` did not exist previously until I tried creating it.

For this reason, I just appended the `cd ~/different/folder` command to `~/.bashrc` instead:

```
echo "cd ~/different/folder" >> ~/.bashrc
```